# GWT+Spring+Hibernate ERROR 404

Tags: java, xml, spring, gwt, servlets

When I try to send a message to the server I get the error 404 .
Help me resolve this problem, please.

> Sending request to the server: 1 Name Sname job Server replies: An
>   error occurred while attempting to contact the server. Please check
>   your network connection and try again. The error is :
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404 HTTP ERROR:
>   404
>
> NOT_FOUND
>
> RequestURI=/gwtspringtestnomaven/springGwtServices/employeeService
>
> Powered by Jetty://

my code:

web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
             version="2.5"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

       <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <listener>
     <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
     </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
     <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet
     </servlet-class>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>

      <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/com.javacodegeeks.Gwtspringtestnomaven/springGwtServices/*</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping> 

      <!-- Default page to serve -->
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Gwtspringtestnomaven.html</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

    </web-app>
```

Gwtspringtestnomaven.gwt.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='gwtspringtestnomaven'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='com.javacodegeeks.client.Gwtspringtestnomaven'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

EmployeeServiceAsync.java:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.shared.services;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.ServiceDefTarget;
import com.javacodegeeks.shared.dto.EmployeeDTO;

public interface EmployeeServiceAsync {


    void deleteEmployee(long employeeId, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);

    void findEmployee(long employeeId, AsyncCallback<EmployeeDTO> callback);

    void saveEmployee(long employeeId, String name, String surname,
        String jobDescription, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);

    void saveOrUpdateEmployee(long employeeId, String name, String surname,
        String jobDescription, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);

    void updateEmployee(long employeeId, String name, String surname,
        String jobDescription, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);

    public static final class Util
    {
    private static EmployeeServiceAsync instance;
    public static final EmployeeServiceAsync getInstance()
    {
    if ( instance == null )
    {
    instance = (EmployeeServiceAsync) GWT.create( EmployeeService.class );

    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) instance;
    target.setServiceEntryPoint( GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "springGwtServices/employeeService " );

    }
    return instance;
    }
    private Util()
    {
    // Utility class should not be instanciated
    }
    }

}
```

EmployeeServiceImpl.java:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.server.services; 

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct; 
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy; 

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service; 
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation; 
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional; 

import com.javacodegeeks.server.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import com.javacodegeeks.shared.dto.EmployeeDTO;
import com.javacodegeeks.shared.services.EmployeeService;

@Service("employeeService") 
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService { 


 @Autowired 
 private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO; 

 @PostConstruct 
 public void init() throws Exception { 
 } 

 @PreDestroy 
 public void destroy() { 
 } 

 public EmployeeDTO findEmployee(long employeeId) { 

  return employeeDAO.findById(employeeId); 

 } 

 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class) 
 public void saveEmployee(long employeeId, String name, String surname, String jobDescription) throws Exception { 
  EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = employeeDAO.findById(employeeId); 

  if(employeeDTO == null) { 
   employeeDTO = new EmployeeDTO(employeeId, name,surname, jobDescription); 
   employeeDAO.persist(employeeDTO); 
  } 

 } 

 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class) 
 public void updateEmployee(long employeeId, String name, String surname, String jobDescription) throws Exception { 

  EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = employeeDAO.findById(employeeId); 

  if(employeeDTO != null) { 
   employeeDTO.setEmployeeName(name); 
   employeeDTO.setEmployeeSurname(surname); 
   employeeDTO.setJob(jobDescription); 
  } 

 } 

 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class) 
 public void deleteEmployee(long employeeId) throws Exception { 

  EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = employeeDAO.findById(employeeId); 

  if(employeeDTO != null) 
   employeeDAO.remove(employeeDTO); 

 } 

 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class) 
 public void saveOrUpdateEmployee(long employeeId, String name, String surname, String jobDescription) throws Exception { 
   System.out.println("into SaveOrUpdate");
  EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = new EmployeeDTO(employeeId, name,surname, jobDescription); 
  System.out.println("SaveOrUpdate good");
  employeeDAO.merge(employeeDTO); 
  System.out.println(" SaveOrUpdate out"); 
 } 

}
```

Gwtspringtestnomaven.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the     -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into                -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration   -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype is not supported. -->

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <!--                                                               -->
    <!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
    <!--                                                               -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Gwtspringtestnomaven.css">

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- Any title is fine                         -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
    <!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
    <!-- be added before this line.                -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <script type="text/javascript"language="javascript" <!-- здесь кст пишет :Attribute (language) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents. -->
 src="gwtspringtestnomaven/gwtspringtestnomaven.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <!--                                           -->
  <!-- The body can have arbitrary html, or      -->
  <!-- you can leave the body empty if you want  -->
  <!-- to create a completely dynamic UI.        -->
  <!--                                           -->
  <body>

    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>

    <h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1>

   <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Please enter employee info (id name surname job):</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="employeeInfoFieldContainer"></td>
        <td id="updateEmployeeButtonContainer"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Please enter employee id:</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="employeeIdFieldContainer"></td>
        <td id="retrieveEmployeeButtonContainer"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="color:red;" id="errorLabelContainer"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<url-pattern>/com.javacodegeeks.Gwtspringtestnomaven/springGwtServices/*</url-pattern>` vs. `RequestURI=/gwtspringtestnomaven/springGwtServices/employeeService`?

Comment: Thanks! No more ERROR 404!! But now I get ERROR 500 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j. I reslove this trable myself!

Comment: Ok, glad it helped, I made it an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Spring service servlet mapping includes a package name: `<url-pattern>/com.javacodegeeks.Gwtspringtestnomaven/springGwtServices/*</url-p‌​attern>`. Your request URI uses a short name relative to the webb app name: `RequestURI=/gwtspringtestnomaven/springGwtServices/employeeService`. Solution: Fix the servlet mapping so it points to the correct location.